# What would a compose method in the BiFunction interface look like?

Tags: java, function, functional-interface, function-composition

The `Function` interface has the `compose()` and `andThen()` methods while the `BiFunction` interface only has the `andThen()` method. My question is simply how could the corresponding method be implemented? I'll try to represent this graphically.

[image: BiFunction without compose]

The single letters are parameterized types as defined by Java's `Function` and `BiFunction` interfaces. Arrows are the flow of inputs and outputs. Boxes with connected arrows are functions. The dotted box just shows how the apply method is used.

Answer (score 2):

The `Function`'s `Compose()` and `andThen()` methods are straightforward since a `Function` has one input and one output and therefore can only be strung sequentially with another in two ways.

Since a `BiFunction` has one output, the "after" function has to be something with only one corresponding input, and `Function` fits the bill. And since it has two inputs, the "before" function needs to be something with two outputs? You can't have a method return two things, so there seemingly can't be a "before". The return type of each of these methods is the same as the interface they are defined in, so the proposed method should return a `BiFunction`.

**My proposal** then is a method that takes two `Function`s as input and returns a `BiFunction`. I'm not sure what else it could even be. It couldn't be two `BiFunction`s because then the return type would have to be a `QuaterFunction`.

Here is the code as it would be written in the Java Library:

```java
public interface BiFunction<T, U, R> {
    // apply()...

    default <V, W> BiFunction<V, W, R> compose(
        Function<? super V, ? extends T> beforeLeft,
        Function<? super W, ? extends U> beforeRight) {
        
        Objects.requireNonNull(beforeLeft);
        Objects.requireNonNull(beforeRight);
        return (V v, W w) -> apply(beforeLeft.apply(v), beforeRight.apply(w));
    }

    // andThen()...
}
```

Here is the finished graph:

[image]

Here it is in use:

```java
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> add = Integer::sum;
Function<Integer, Integer> abs = Math::abs;
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addAbs = add.compose(abs, abs);
System.out.println(addAbs.apply(-2, -3));

// output: 5
```

If you want to actually test this, you can do something like this:

```java
public interface BiFunctionWithCompose<T, U, R> extends BiFunction<T, U, R> {...
```

Or like this:

```
package myutil;
public interface BiFunction<T, U, R> extends java.util.function.BiFunction<T, U, R> {...
```

---

I have no idea if this will be useful to anyone, but it was really fun to think through and write. Have a wonderful day.